# Responsivness issue with multiple item slider in slick.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Problem that I'm facing is that the slider images are not responsive... I don't have a clue what I'm doing wrong, I followed the instructions from the demos on the slick.js web page.

What I want to achieve: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/overview/ (scroll over to the footer, there is a 3 planet slider (9 images in total), image has a  html a tag and there is text below the image).

Image of my issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1gWd.png

See what I want to happen when resizing the browser:
https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/overview/

Maybe useful information: When I put img tag without it being in a div or a tag it works perfectly...

JS/Jquery:

```
$('.slider-inner').slick({
    arrows: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 800,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick- 
  theme.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<footer>

       <h2>More Locations</h2>
        <div class="slider-inner">

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="jupiter.html">
              <img src="../img/slide1.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="earth.html">
              <img src="../img/slide2.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="mercury.html">
              <img src="../img/slide3.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="mars.html">
              <img src="../img/slide4.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="venus.html">
              <img src="../img/slide5.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="saturn.html">
              <img src="../img/slide6.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="uranus.html">
              <img src="../img/slide7.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="neptune.html">
              <img src="../img/slide8.png">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-item">
            <a href="moon.html">
              <img src="../img/slide9.png">
            </a>
          </div>

      </div>
</footer>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
  footer {
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-family: 'Gayathri', sans-serif;
  }

  footer h2 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slick was a really nice slider, but it’s 2020, even the developer doesn’t do anything with it anymore for years. My advice is to stop using Slick and JQuery.

Comment: Okay, I knew that, but I'm doing my first bigger project in Vanilla JS, so I figured slick would fit... Anyways, thanks for advice.